# Generic function return value can not be specified creating generic methods

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have this method which is required to convert a list of int values to a list of the appropriate enum values.

The issue is that the Select is returning an object type as I have not specified the return type to the generic function as the return type is also generic.

```
    public static Tout Convert<Tout, Tin>(IList<Tin> reply)
    {
        Type resultListElementType = typeof(Tout).GetGenericArguments()[0];
        MethodInfo setEnumValueMethod = typeof(EnumUtils).GetGenericMethod("SetEnumValue", new Type[] { typeof(Tin) });
        MethodInfo setEnumValueGenericMethod = setEnumValueMethod.MakeGenericMethod(resultListElementType, typeof(Tin));
        Tout result = (Tout)(dynamic)reply.Select(v => setEnumValueGenericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { v })).ToList();
        return result;
    }
```

The Generic function signature is as below

```
    public static Tout SetEnumValue<Tout, Tin>(Tin value)
```

Is there any way that I can also configure the return type of the generic function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already doing that. You bind `TIn` to `typeof(Tin)`. The problem is somewhere else:

```
Tout result = (Tout)(dynamic)reply.Select(v => setEnumValueGenericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { v })).ToList();
```

This gives you a `List<object>`. Cast each individual value to the correct type:

```
List<Tout> result = reply.Select(v => (Tout)(dynamic)setEnumValueGenericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { v })).ToList();
```

And change
     public static Tout Convert(IList reply)

to

```
 public static List<Tout> Convert<Tout, Tin>(IList<Tin> reply)
```

Comment: It is Tout that has the problem.  I am looking for a way to make the generic function with the RETURN type.By changing the convert I move the problem out a level, but does not solve it for me.  I reach a point where I don't have control over the API so I need to be able to specify the return type.  I am aware I am binding the input parameters.

Comment: Will Tout (in the unchanged signature) always be a `List` at runtime? In that case we'd actually need to plug back in the cast that you originally did and that I moved into the Select.; Anyway, this is kind of a dirty thing. I wonder what you need this hackery for?

Comment: The real issue is that Invoke via reflection does not support the return type appropriately and only ever returns object thereby requiring a cast.

Comment: The APi I am using takes a generic that includes the list, or may not as it could also just be a plain object or even a dictionary.  Trying to create a level of generics utilising that is causing confusion.  I have ended up taking your solution and intercepting the calls and handling the list processing separately.  Thanks for the help.